# How to mock current date?

Tags: java, unit-testing, date, mockito, powermockito

I have a method in my code which verifies that current day is business. it checks database calendar for this.

method looks like this:

```
public boolean iBusinessDayToday() {
      LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
      //logic with today
}
```

I need to write unit tests for this.

I want that unit test doesn't depends in week day.

What do you think need this issue to use powerMockito to mock `LocalDate.now()` ?

Comment: Can you change the code, e.g. in `iBusinessDayToday()`?

Comment: As the Javadoc of `LocalDate.now()` warns: `Using this method will prevent the ability to use an alternate clock for testing because the clock is hard-coded.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative would be to pass the clock to the method:

```
public boolean iBusinessDayToday() {
  return iBusinessDayToday(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
}

@VisibleForTesting
boolean iBusinessDayToday(Clock clock) {
      LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(clock);
      //logic with today
}
```

Now you can test the second method and pass a [a fixed clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) - no need to use a mocking framework.

Comment: It might be better to make the `Clock` a member of the class, passed to its constructor.  Or to change the method to `isBusinessDay(LocalDate day)`. The question is what class is responsible for defining "today"? That's the class which should own the `Clock`.